# Thymeleaf Fill object with data?

Tags: java, html, spring, maven, thymeleaf

i'm trying to send object of user to my html page and fill his attribute but however i do that it gives me many errors "invaild setter and getter" or "interface class"
this is the declaration of the object

```
User user = new Student() ;
```

Note that User is interface and 
Student is Class implements User
here my user interface

```
public interface User{


public Account getAccount();
    public void setAccount(Account account);
    public double getScore();
    public void setScore(double score);
    double getGameScore(int gameID);
    public void updateScore(double score);
    public void addGame(int gameID, double score);
    public Map<Integer, Double> getPlayedGames();
    public void setPlayedGames(Map<Integer, Double>();  
}
```

this is class Student

```
public class Student implements User {
    private int id ; 
    Account account = new Account();
    private Map<Integer, Double> playedGames = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();    
    /**setter & getter*/
}
```

and my html form

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/view/Register}" th:object="${user}"
    method="post">
    <p> Name: <input type="text" th:field="*${user.getAccount().userName}" required="required" /></p>
    <p>Email : <input type="text" th:field="${user.getAccount().email}" required="required" /></p>
    <p>Password : <input type="text" th:field="${user.getAccount().password}" required="required" /></p>
    <p> Profile :<input type="file" name="picture" /></p>
    <p>Male : <input type="radio" th:field="${user.getAccount().gender}" value="Male"
            checked="true" /> Female : <input type="radio" th:field="${user.getAccount().gender}"
            value="Female" /></p>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Pass from Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "view/Register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String register(Model model) {

    User user = new Student () ; 
    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    return "view/Register";
}
```

how could i get it work ?

Comment: can you show us how are you passing it from the controller?

Comment: When asking for help, it's important to include the error message you are seeing. Besides that, it makes no sense to use an interface on a class that just has getters/setters.

Comment: this how i pass it from controller 

@RequestMapping(value = "view/Register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String register(Model model) {

    User user = new Student () ; 
    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    return "view/Register";
}

Comment: i have many of error message because i tried multi solution 
and it doesn't have only setter and getter beside i have another type of User so i needed it to be interface